# How to replace all <a href="..."> links with a JavaScript window.location link for use in a Web App?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a Progressive Web App for iOS and whenever I click on a link, it opens in Safari and not within the app. I'd like to use JavaScript to replace all the `<a href="https://example.com">Example</a>` with JavaScript window.location links so that links open in the app (for example: `<a href="javascript:void" onclick="window.location='http://example.com'">Example</a>`). I would like to avoid the use of jQuery, as it adds extra bloat to my app and I am trying to keep a minimal user experience.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Googling "javascript set HTML attribute"? What else have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the DOM (Document Object Model) like that can cause you more problems than get you to the solution you want.  I recommend using an event listener and preventDefault.

Here are the relevant docs per those methods:

- addEventListener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
- preventDefault: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Here is a super basic example, your mileage may vary based on whatever framework you're using for your progressive app, consider this more of a starting point rather than a complete solution.

```
<pre>
  <a href="https://example.com/Link_1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="https://example.com/Link_2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="https://example.com/Link_3">Link 3</a>
  <a href="https://example.com/Link_4">Link 4</a>
  <a href="https://example.com/Link_5">Link 5</a>
</pre>
<script>
// Array of the anchor (a) elements.
const links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

// Loop the array
// Yes you can use a foreach or whatever you want instead
for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
  // On each of the links add a click event listener
  links[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // this in the event is the element, I'm giving assigning it here for clarity
    const link = this;
    // preventDefault stops the link from being followed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Set the window.location.href to the link's href attribute.
    window.location.href = link.getAttribute('href');
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thanks for sharing that little example.

Comment: Happy to help.  Be sure to read through the MDN pages on those methods, so you have a good understanding of exactly what is going on.  You can do a lot of stuff with the DOM with the built-in methods without using additional libraries.